# Compare 2 columns of two differences file csv, or 2 databese tables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I'm new in PHP language , I have 2 csv files that contains:first 2 columns the first with some countries prefixes and the second with name of correspondent country.
The second has 2 column the first has phone numbers and the second  correspondent country.
I need to make a compare of this 2 files if I found matching  of prefixes, I need that this number to be deleted , and the rest of phone number to be added to another file. 
For example:

```
    First File x.csv         Second file y.csv
```

```
prefix  country          country     phone number
4474    UK               UK          44793245683...  
347466  Spain            Spain       34746689211345
3278    Belgium          Belgium     324568845212.....
                         Switzerland 4189544562131...
                         UK          4474321546588464...
                         Italy       39324566546548345
                         UK          4478564684151...   
</pre>
```

So I want in another fil z.csv this output:

```
    country     phone number
    UK          44793245683...

    Belgium     324568845212.....
    Switzerland 4189544562131...
    Italy       39324566546548345
    UK          4478564684151...
```

This means that in this numbers has found match of prefixes:
    
    Country     Phone NUmber      Match Prefix
    Spain       34746689211345    347466
    UK          4474321546588464  4474

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have try with selecting  of 2 tables in mysql  ,  and make compare with fetching data, and I check this with condition if(preg_match("/^".$row1['x']."/",$row1['y']))
              {}

Comment: I think this question is too broad - the implementation for comparing CSV files VS. comparing DB  tables will be very different. Try to narrow it down a bit to a specific issue. For starters, I would look at using SQL to compare the 2 tables instead of PHP. Another issue - what should the expected output of the comparison be?

Comment: I know that is different  implementation , but for me solve the same  problem. Output of comparison should be like this

Comment: I thought that I make a question maybe generally way , because I need to learn and not to copy and paste somewhere else. But specifically , I have 2 csv files , 1 has country prefixes and name of country, and another has phone numbers  and corresponds country, So if one of these prefixes founded to list of numbers, I need to list this phone numbers, else I need to list the rest.

Comment: OK - can you please edit your question with that information, some example data showing country/prefix/phone numbers, the relevant code that is not working as intended, and also the expected output? With that information, someone will be able to help you with your issue.